# Crystal Report Export & Print Button in Viewer Not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Am Dispalying a crystal report using javascript Popup :

```
 window.open("reports_1_cox.aspx");
```

Aspx :

```
   <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="coxReportIdVw" runat="server"   Height="50px" 
       ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="350px"/>
```

I can see the report is loaded properly but when I am trying to export or print the report it is throwing me this error :

***Failed to export using the options you specified. Please check your options and try again.***

have tried placing Viewer in Update Panel but no luck.

Comment: Will this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632386/crystal-report-viewer-built-in-export-button-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have copied this folder **crystalreportviewers13** from my **BuisnessObjects** installed folder to my app path and it worked properly.